# Angular ngClass and click event for toggling class

Tags: angular, angular-ng-class

In Angular, I would like to use `ngClass` and click event to toggle class. I looked through online but some are angular1 and there isn't any clear instruction or example. Any help will be much appreciated!

In HTML, I have the following:

```html
<div class="my_class" (click)="clickEvent($event)" ngClass="{'active': toggle}">
  Some content
</div>
```

In `.ts`:

```js
clickEvent(event) {
  // Haven't really got far
  var targetEle = event.srcElement.attributes.class;
}
```

Answer (score 160, accepted):

This should work for you.

In .html:

```html
<div class="my_class" (click)="clickEvent()"  
    [ngClass]="status ? 'success' : 'danger'">                
    Some content
</div>
```

In .ts:

```js
status: boolean = false;
clickEvent(){
    this.status = !this.status;       
}
```

Comment: Just a quick question. The first click adds the class just fine, but the second click doesn't seem to work. From your code, I don't see how it changes the `status` back to `false`.

Comment: made changes to my code., you can set it to false initially and then the function will toggle the bool value to true<-> false.

Answer (score 76):

Instead of having to create a function in the ts file you can toggle a variable from the template itself. You can then use the variable to apply a specific class to the element. Like so-

component.html -

```html
<div (click)="status=!status"  
    [ngClass]="status ? 'success' : 'danger'">                
    Some content
</div>
```

So when status is true the class success is applied. When it is false danger class is applied.

<del>This will work without any additional code in the ts file.</del>
EDIT: Recent versions of angular require the variable to be declared in the controller -
component.ts -

```js
status: boolean = false;
```

Comment: Would you have to declare "status" in the template?

Comment: @webworm no, you do not need to declare `status` in the template.

Comment: Is it possible to use this approach also for a div inside an ngFor ? Because I try it, but it seems that angular change the class to all the div created with ngFor, not only to the one that I click; thanks.

Comment: Getting error that the - Property 'status' does not exist on type <Component Name>

Comment: @sin2akshay looks like things have changed in angular recently so you'll have to declare the variable first. I've updated the answer above.

Answer (score 43):

Angular6 using the renderer2 without any variables and a clean template:

template:

```html
<div (click)="toggleClass($event,'testClass')"></div>
```

in ts:

```js
toggleClass(event: any, className: string) {
    const hasClass = event.target.classList.contains(className);

    if (hasClass) {
        this.renderer.removeClass(event.target, className);
    } else {
        this.renderer.addClass(event.target, className);
    }
}
```

One could put this in a directive too ;)

Comment: Should not use reserved keyword class.

Comment: this solution not work in my case

Comment: What is the issue on your side? Maybe I can help : )

Answer (score 16):

`ngClass` should be wrapped in square brackets as this is a property binding. Try this:

```html
<div class="my_class" (click)="clickEvent($event)"  [ngClass]="{'active': toggle}">                
    Some content
</div>
```

In your component:

```js
//define the toogle property
private toggle : boolean = false;
              
//define your method
clickEvent(event){
   //if you just want to toggle the class; change toggle variable.
   this.toggle = !this.toggle;       
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 13):

If you're looking for an HTML only way of doing this in angular...

```
<div #myDiv class="my_class" (click)="myDiv.classList.toggle('active')">
  Some content
</div>
```

The important bit is the `#myDiv` part.

It's a HTML Node reference, so you can use that variable as if it was assigned to `document.querySelector('.my_class')`

**NOTE:** this variable is scope specific, so you can use it in `*ngFor` statements

Answer (score 3):

We can also use ngClass to assign multiple CSS classes based on multiple conditions as below:

```
<div
  [ngClass]="{
  'class-name': trueCondition,
  'other-class': !trueCondition
}"
></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to toggle text with a toggle button.

HTMLfile which is using bootstrap:

```
<input class="btn" (click)="muteStream()"  type="button"
          [ngClass]="status ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-danger'" 
          [value]="status ? 'unmute' : 'mute'"/>
```

TS file:

```
muteStream() {
   this.status = !this.status;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So normally you would create a backing variable in the class and toggle it on click and tie a class binding to the variable. Something like:

```
@Component(
    selector:'foo',
    template:`<a (click)="onClick()"
                         [class.selected]="wasClicked">Link</a>
    `)
export class MyComponent {
    wasClicked = false;

    onClick() {
        this.wasClicked= !this.wasClicked;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

Html.

```html
<button *ngFor="let color of colors; let index=index" class="example1" 
        (click)="selectColor(index)" [class.choose__color]="viewMode == index">
    <mat-icon>fiber_manual_record</mat-icon>
</button>
```

css.

```css
.example1:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.choose__color {
     border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

ts.

```js
selectColor(index: any) {
    this.viewMode = index;
}
```

Comment: How to unset color on component blur (unselect)?