# How to open dropdown menu onclick using javascript in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement drop down menu items on click using javascript without using jquery in angular

I tried creating seperate javascript file and specified the file path in script in angular json file. 
It is not working. What are the other ways to do this?

```
<div class="tab-dropdown">
                  <div id="dropdown" (click)="dropClick()">Open Dropdown</div>
               </div>
               <ul class="nav" role="tablist" id="navdrop">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link active" href="#all" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="addprevtext()">All</a>
                  </li> -->
                  <li class="nav-item ">
                     <a class="nav-link " href="#social" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="addprevtext()">HR</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#digital" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"
                        onclick="addprevtext()">Marketing
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#crm" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="changetext()">Customer Service</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#ticketing" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"
                        onclick="changetext()">Operations</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#coreSystem" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="changetext()">Insurance</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#dms" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="changetext()">Financial Services</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#manu" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="changetext()">Manufacturing
                           </a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                           <a class="nav-link" href="#health" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="changetext()">Healthcare & Pharma

                              </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="#it" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="changetext()">IT

                                 </a>
                           </li>

               </ul>
```

js File

```
function showDropdown() {
document.getElementById("dropdown").onclick = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("navdrop").classList.toggle("show");
}
}
```

ts file

```
dropClick() {
    showDropdown();

  }
```

Drop down menu should open on clicking

Here's an MCVE: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wrmrvu

Comment: In Angular I want

Comment: Angular version 7.2.11

Comment: also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44535515/angular-ngclass-and-click-event-for-toggling-class If still not able to get that done then let us know

Comment: Here is my link https://angular-wrmrvu.stackblitz.io

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wrmrvu

Comment: Check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kqx21b Updated and working

Comment: Have you tried? Is is working?

Comment: It worked. How to close the dropdown once I click on particular menu item ?

Comment: NOTE: Javascript is not required to make dropdown menus.  There are other methods that keep things simpler - pure CSS with hover is one, or using HTML hidden checkboxes and labels is another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with [`@ViewChild()`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) and [`ElementRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef), no need to write extra code in the seperate .js file or no need to create any directive.

TS Code:

Import this:

```
import {  ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
```

and:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  @ViewChild('navdrop', null) navdrop: ElementRef; // Angular Version 8
  @ViewChild('navdrop') navdrop: ElementRef; // Angular Version < 8

  dropClick() {
    this.navdrop.nativeElement.classList.toggle("visibility");
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.visibility {
  display: none;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
                           This is important
                               \/\/\/\/
<ul class="nav" role="tablist" #navdrop id="navdrop">
   ... 
    your other HTML markup
   ...
</ul>
```

[`Working_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kqx21b)

Comment: just wondering, how can you create a class called show with display none in it

Comment: @Mcanic Well, its all about naming convensions, Suggest anything if you can name it well!

Comment: Clicking on the menu and showing the menu items, how can you make the menu hover over existing content, and not taking up space and pushing the existing content down?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to be able to open several dropdowns at the same time and you need it to close if you press outside of it. You will need at service to control that.

Main directive

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[dropDown]'
})
export class Dropdown implements AfterContentInit, OnDestroy {
    private toggleSubscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
    private outSideSubscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
    @ContentChild(DropdownToogle) ddToggle: DropdownToogle;
    @HostBinding('class.dropdown') dropDownClass = true;
    @HostBinding('class.opened') opened: boolean;

    constructor(private element: ElementRef, private dropDownService: DropdownService) {
    }

    ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        this.toggleSubscription = this.ddToggle.clicked.subscribe(() => {
            this.opened = !this.opened;
            if (this.opened) {
                this.outSideSubscription = this.dropDownService.getAppClick().subscribe((target: any) => {
                    const clickedInside = this.element.nativeElement.contains(target);
                    if (!clickedInside) {
                        this.outSideSubscription.unsubscribe();
                        this.opened = false;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                this.outSideSubscription.unsubscribe();
            }
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.toggleSubscription.unsubscribe();
        this.outSideSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

And the dropdown toggle

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[dropDownToggle]'
})
export class DropdownToogle {
    @Output() clicked = new EventEmitter();
    @HostBinding('class.dropdown-toggle') true = true;
    @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onclick() {
        this.clicked.emit();
    }

}
```

And the service

```
@Injectable()
export class DropdownService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();
    constructor() {
        fromEvent(document, 'click').subscribe((event: any) => {
            this.subject.next(event.target);
        });
    }
    getAppClick(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Basic css

```
.dropdown{
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
.dropdown .opened .dropdown-menu {
      display: block;
  }

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 160px;
}
```

You will need to add styling for the buttons or the anchorlinks within the dropdown
And finally the usage

```
<div dropDown>
  <button dropDownToggle>A dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <button>Do something</button>
    <button>Something else</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the css i correct. I actually use sass but rewrote it on the fly

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution for bootstrap 4 with angular.

In your `package.json` you need

```
dependencies: {
  "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.2",
  "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
  ...
}
```

In your `app.module.ts` file you will need to add a module

```
imports: [
  ...
  NgbModule.forRoot()
]
```

All of the above is to enable the following 3 directives: `ngbDropdown`, `ngbDropdownToggle` and `ngbDropdownMenu`.

So, now you can use those in the template files of your components. e.g. for a dropdown with caption "More ..." and one menu item "Item", you would need something like this:

```
  <div ngbDropdown>
    <a ngbDropdownToggle
      class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
      id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
      data-toggle="dropdown"
      aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      More...
    </a>
    <div ngbDropdownMenu
      class="dropdown-menu"
      aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
```

You can find more examples in [the official documentation of ng bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples).