# in dynamic div - on click highlight color

Tags: html, css, angular, angular5

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav--small nodeLevel newColor" id="rowItem-{{i}}" *ngFor="let root of rootzTemplates; let i=index" (click)="nodeClickLevel1(root,i)">
    <p style="padding: 19px 1px;color: #fff; text-align: center;">
        {{root}} 
    </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .activeColor {
   background-color: grey;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }
        
nodeClickLevel1(root, id){
     this.myTag = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector("#rowItem-" + id);
     this.myTag.classList.remove('activeColor');
     this.myTag.classList.add('activeColor');
}
```

Now div is dynamic, say number of div element is 6, on click event i have to change particular clicked div background-color to grey and rest of color should remain same.
Now if I click on div say 2, only 2nd div has highlight with grey color, rest of the color should remain same and vice versa.

Comment: You can pass the event on click as follows `(click)="nodeClickLevel1(event)` and access the same element in the method via `event.target`. Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51893693/8712609).

Answer (score 0):

Change your function like this

```
nodeClickLevel1(root, id){
    this.myTag = root
}
```

change your template code like this

```
[class.newColor]="root === myTag"
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be much simpler, no need for troublesome `ElementRef`, no need for index ids, etc.
So here is the code:

```js
//our root app component
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  // templateUrl: "app.html",
  template: `
    <div class="nav--small nodeLevel newColor" [class.activeColor]="root === myTag" *ngFor="let root of rootzTemplates" (click)="nodeClickLevel1(root)">
            <p style="padding: 19px 1px;color: #fff;    text-align: center;">{{root}}</p>
</div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name: string;
  constructor() { }
  protected myTag:any;
  public rootzTemplates: any[] = ["first", "2nd", "3rd"];

  nodeClickLevel1(root){
    this.myTag = root;
}
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [App],
  bootstrap: [App],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and css:

```css
.activeColor {
   background-color: grey !important;
}
.nav--small{
   background-color: black;
}
```

Here is the working **PLNKR link**:
http://plnkr.co/edit/oRZa3E5WtYpusKHd