# How does the color change when I press the card in angular?

Tags: angular

I did a filtering. There are 5 categories. Whichever card I press, information is listed according to that card. When I press that card, I want the class to be added and the color to change. How can I do it ?

Comment: PLease show some code.  It's very difficult to answer your coding question with no code shown.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular ngClass and click event for toggling class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44535515/angular-ngclass-and-click-event-for-toggling-class)